# Silverlight fault propagation and UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: wcf, silverlight, exception, authentication

Scenario is a Silverlight client using Wcf service & custom authentication. To mitigate the 500/200 status code problem (avoid EndPointNotFound exception) I've applied the [SilverLightFaultBehaviour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). However, this does not work with [UserNamePasswordValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551936(v=vs.90).aspx) - When a FaultException is thrown from Validate(), it is not caught by the SilverLightFaultMessageInspector's implementation of BeforeSendReply.

So far, the only workaround I've found is using the alternative client stack instead ( `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);`), but there are complications with using it which can no longer be ignored as a lot of our clients are on virtual machines, the silverlight client keeps crashing ( [Silverlight 5 - Debugging npctrl.dll crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382809/silverlight-5-debugging-npctrl-dll-crash) , http://communities.vmware.com/thread/394306?tstart=0 ).

My primary motivation is that I want to be able to distinguish a failed login from a connection error (the following code is from a client-side async callback method, and only works with the Client stack):

```cs
if (e.Error is MessageSecurityException)
{
    this.HasLoginFailed.Value = Captions.Login_FailedLogin;
}
else
{
    this.HasLoginFailed.Value = Captions.Login_FailedConnection;
}
```

Is there any other way of modifying the message sent when throwing a FaultException from UserNamePasswordValidator? Or any conceptually different way of doing custom authentication rather than what I am using which enables me to modify the message status or to keep it 200, or just to be able to distinguish a connection failure from bad credentials?

my server-side code for usernamepassword reg:

```cs
var serviceCredential = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceCredentials>();
serviceCredential.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode =
                    UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom; 
serviceCredential.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator =
                    new MyValidator();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you throw a `FaultException` from `MyValidator`, it is wrapped as the `InnerException` of a `MessageSecurityException`, that's probably why you weren't able to catch it directly as a `FaultException`.

To add some information to the fault you are throwing, what you can do is adding a `FaultCode`:

```
throw new FaultException(
    "Invalid user name or bad password.",
     new FaultCode("BadUserNameOrPassword")
);
```

Then, catch the exception client-side and retrieve your `FaultCode`:

```
try { ... }
catch (MessageSecurityException e)
{
    FaultException fault = (FaultException) e.InnerException;
    String faultCode = fault.Code.Name;
    // you can now display a meaningful error with the faultCode
}
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: Old question of mine - might be irrelevant today, this fix relased in 2013 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2814124/ probably mitigates the  divide by 0 bug on WmWare machines. In any case, the problem was that the exception that arrived on client side was not "typed", nor contained any of the information in the thrown exception. Impossible to tell one exception from another - your solution does not mitigate the original problem.