# Using browser's HTTP stack

Tags: silverlight, vmware, silverlight-5.0, webrequest

I'm trying to solve somehow the problem described here:[Silverlight 5 - Debugging npctrl.dll crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382809/silverlight-5-debugging-npctrl-dll-crash)

They suggest two solutions. One of them is "Stop using the client networking stack".
Not sure what it means but in the app.xaml.cs we have the following line:

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

Does this mean we use client networking stack? if so then how do I switch to browser http stack? I tried both to remove this line and change it to:

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
```

but in both ways when I execute an HTTP request I never get a response. Simply nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

**SOME MORE DETAILS:**

First of all it's an OOB application.
So I changed it to

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp);
```

as I explained above.
I try to execute an HTTP request in the following way:

```
m_restClient = new RestClient
    {
Authority = http://172.30.2.73:8182/;
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
    Deserializer = deserializer,
    Serializer = serializer,
    GetErrorResponseEntityType = GetErrorResponseEntityType,
    Encoding = serializer.ContentEncoding
  };

var request = new RestRequest
    {
      Path = "emulation/parameters",
      Method = WebMethod.Get,
    };

m_restClient.BeginRequest<EmulationParametersResponse>(request, RestGetEmulationParamsCompleted);
```

In the fiddler it seems like I do get a response with status code 200 and I also can see the response there but I put a break point in the callback and deserializer and it doesn't stop there.

Comment: Yes, changing the line you found should do it. Not sure we can help you without more infos. Have you tried Fiddler?

Comment: I've added some more details, please let me know if there is anything else I can add.